# Razor - How do I display data from script in selectList on view?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I'm new to this and can't seem to figure out how to display data from script.  I have two selectLists, clients & profiles. When client changes I need to update a profiles list and display on the view. I have script that gets selected client and in the model the profile list is updated. What I can't figure out is how to use that result on the view. How do I use UnMappedEscheatProfileId that has the returned data?

```
code here

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientId)
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientId)

<select asp-for="ClientId" id="ClientIdKey" 
    class="form-select" asp- 
    items="@Model.UnMappedClients">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>

<select asp-for="EscheatProfile" 
  id="UnMappedEscheatProfileId" class="form- 
  select" asp- 
  items="@Model.UnMappedEscheatProfiles">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>


@section EscheatProfileListUpdateScripts {
<script>

    $('#ClientIdKey').on('change', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '?handler=GetData',
            headers: {
                RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
            data: { "selectedClientId": $("#ClientIdKey").val() },
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (data) {
            $("#UnMappedEscheatProfileId").val(data);

        });
    });
</script>
```

}

```
public IActionResult OnPostGetData(string selectedClientId)
    {
        
         UnMappedEscheatProfiles = new SelectList(_context.vwTaskGroupByClients.Where(c => c.ClientId == selectedClientId && c.EsheatProfileCode != null).Select(a => a.EsheatProfileCode).ToList());
        return new JsonResult(UnMappedEscheatProfiles);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are several suggestions below:

1. You can use `console.log(data)` to check the response for better development.
2. `SelectList` contains five constructors which can be used to populate the dropdownlist. But what you choose is not fit for jquery, because the response data cannot get the value. You need use the following constructor: `public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField);`.
3. Dropdownlist cannot be easily set data like:`$("#UnMappedEscheatProfileId").val(data);`.

Here is a working demo:

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<select asp-for="ClientId" id="ClientIdKey"
        class="form-select" asp-items="@Model.UnMappedClients">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>    
<select asp-for="EscheatProfile"
        id="UnMappedEscheatProfileId" class="form-
  select" asp-items="@Model.UnMappedEscheatProfiles">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>       
@section Scripts {
    <script>    
        $('#ClientIdKey').on('change', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '?handler=GetData',
                headers: {
                    RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                },
                data: { "selectedClientId": $("#ClientIdKey").val() },
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var items = '';
                $.each(data, function (i, clients) {
                    console.log(clients);
                    items += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + clients["text"] + "</option>";
                });
                $(items).insertAfter("#UnMappedEscheatProfileId option");
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{      
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string EscheatProfile { get; set; }

    public SelectList UnMappedClients { get; set; }
    public SelectList UnMappedEscheatProfiles { get; set; }

    public class VWTaskGroupByClient
    {
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public string EsheatProfileCode { get; set; }
    }
    public class Clients
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        var data = new List<Clients>()
        {
            new Clients(){Id=1,Name="c1"},
            //.....
            new Clients(){Id=4,Name="c4"}
        };
        UnMappedClients = new SelectList(data, "Id", "Name");
    }
    public IActionResult OnPostGetData(string selectedClientId)
    {
        var data = _context.vwTaskGroupByClients.Where(c => c.ClientId == selectedClientId && c.EsheatProfileCode != null).Select(a => a.EsheatProfileCode).ToList();
        
        UnMappedEscheatProfiles = new SelectList(data, "EsheatProfileCode", "EsheatProfileCode");
        return new JsonResult(UnMappedEscheatProfiles);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rena.  It works!  However, I have dup insertions. First client selection is make #UnMappedEscheatProfileId is populated by what's returned from the model, which is what I want. But when client is changes again previous values plus new values from latest selections are displayed in the dropdown. I want to only display current selection values.  I see that on the model side the correct records are returned but something is cached somewhere!   can it be this?: $(items).insertAfter("#UnMappedEscheatProfileId option");

Comment: Hi @AliShiil, if it works for you, remember to accept as answer. For new issue, please post a new thread and share your code with us.